# Using a multi-character delimiter in Cloud Data fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am trying to read a csv file in cloud datafusion. The csv file uses a multi-character (i.e. ~^~)delimiter. When i try to parse the column using a custom delimiter the tool only considers the first character and splits the file accordingly. I end up with more columns than what is required, plus since the data may have the character even the split is not perfect.

I tries using several patterns not just the one mentioned above, but each time its the same result

How do i parse files where the data is delimited using a multi-char delimiter. Is there a setting that can be used. Is there a separate transform that can be used to parse the file before using the wrangler?

In the assignment i am working on i an limited to use only cloud data fusion as my etl tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use the following directive:

split-to-columns

Comment: The split-to-columns did the trick, I had tried to use the directive earlier however did not occur to me to the escape the character ^ . :P